# Background image size

Tags: html, web, size, background-image

What is the best size of background image to use for website?
I'll use different image sizes (I understood that it is necessary), but should I stick to these proportions?

http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_resolution_higher.asp

I need images of landscape, so some photo images will be used as background images, not patterns.

Comment: [w3fools, a lesson on why w3schools is bad](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: You can use media queries, there is info about them on [the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as a side note w3schools is not part of the W3C, so I don't recommend linking to them. See more about that matter [here](http://w3fools.com/).

---

As far as a background-size goes, I'd say it depends on the background. If it's just a pattern then why not make the pattern one image then tile it?

If it's a photo of say, a countryside and it doesn't matter if parts are chopped off because of smaller screen sizes, make it large.

If it's important that users see all of the background then I'd stick to smaller backgrounds. A little trick I like to do, is make the background fade off into the background color, so it looks as if the background-image is huge, when really, it's small.

Hope this advice helped! :)

Comment: Hi Jordan, this helps. I need photos as backgrounds, so probably it would be the best to use some smaller images and then to fade off, like you suggested.

Comment: Yeah, could you mark this as the solved answer? Just so anyone else who comes across this question, they'll know what helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
    background: /*your image*/ 400px 300px;
}
```